# Does Mac OS X come with a native ncdu utility?

Tags: macos

I’m getting the below command not found error whilst issuing `ncdu`.

```
ncdu /home
-bash: ncdu: command not found
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 20):

The answer is No! Mac OS X doesn’t come with a built-in ncdu, but you can easily get it via `Homebrew`. You just need to issue the below command and hit `ENTER`:

```
brew install ncdu
```

You can lookup the available version by issuing:

```
brew info ncdu


ncdu: stable 1.15.1 (bottled), HEAD
NCurses Disk Usage
https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/ncdu.rb
License: MIT
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 3,396 (30 days), 19,142 (90 days), 59,851 (365 days)
install-on-request: 3,313 (30 days), 18,459 (90 days), 57,506 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```